# Visual Studio System.ValueTuple assembly error when creating a NodeJS project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017

I am running `Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.0)` with `.NET Framework 4.6.01055` on `Windows 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSB 64-bit (10.0, Build 10240)`.

Upon creating a new NodeJS project, for example: `New->Javascript->Node.js->Blank Node.js Console Application`

When the `.njsproj` file opens, I get this error:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio

Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.2.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

[image: Visual Studio error]

I've uninstalled and reinstalled .NET Core and Visual Studio, yet I'm getting the same error.  How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

Installing .NET Framework 4.7.2 fixed this issue for me

Comment: The `.NET Framework 4.7.2` is not supported on Version 1507 and 1511 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-10  Starting to feel like Mac OS X circa 2004.

Give me a few days to upgrade and test.